# Scheduled task in Plesk 12 windows not running

Tags: plesk, cron-task

I've setup a scheduled task as being explained in the plesk manual; but it doesn't run at all.

Path to an executable file is:
C:\Program Files (x86)\Parallels\Parallels Panel\Additional\PleskPHP5\php.exe

Arguments:
C:\Inetpub\vhosts\domain.com\domain.com\scripttorun.php

As for the argument; it's correct that there are 2 domains in the path. 
Can somebody give me any advice where to investigate next because i tried a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Last folder looks strange for me:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Parallels\Parallels Panel
```

I don't remember that Plesk used "Parallels Panel" folder for any version.

In my installation there is:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Parallels\Plesk
```

Anyway you can try to use "%plesk_dir%" (always use quotes!) instead of "C:\Program Files (x86)\Parallels\Parallels Panel"

So your cron task will be like:

```
"%plesk_dir%\Additional\PleskPHP5\php.exe" C:\Inetpub\vhosts\domain.com\domain.com\scripttorun.php
```

Just want to say that in up coming Plesk 12.5(not released yet) setup of cron tasks will be much easier.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Oleg for your answer.
We found the solution.
Apparently the PHP version number is also mentioned in the folder structure of plesk. And you were right, also the 'panel' is not needed.

So the working executable path is:

C:\Program Files (x86)\Parallels\Plesk\Additional\PleskPHP54\php.exe